# Find All MP4 Files With DTS or AC3/A52 Audio?

Tags: audio, spotlight

Okay, so after spending a lot of time encoding (or re-encoding) files to mp4's hoping they'd be compatible with iTunes, it turns out that iTunes won't play files with DTS or AC3/A52 audio, so I'm going to have to re-encode the audio on such files to AAC (where before I simply passed it through).

Anyway, I need a way to find all files with these audio types or, if it's easier, all MP4 files **without** AAC audio.

What is the best way to do this? Ideally I'd like to use Spotlight if I can, though I've tried several search criteria without much luck, but I'll also accept answers that use Terminal-based solutions, as I'll probably use `ffmpeg` to convert the audio anyway.

Comment: I'm working on a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a shell script. This will print any file that has a different codec.
Set the directory and extension to look for.

```
#!/bin/zsh
directory=~/Music
extension=m4a
codec=aac

find $directory -type f -name "*.$extension" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
    file_codec="$(ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -print_format json $file | jq '.streams[0].codec_name')"
    [[ "${file_codec//\"}" != $codec ]] && echo $file
done
```

You need `ffmpeg` and `jq`. You can install both of them from [homebrew](http://brew.sh).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I should have known it'd be something the `ffmpeg` toolbox! Just a note, I managed to simplify the command to not require `jq` with the following change: `ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -select_streams a -show_entries stream=codec_name "$file" | grep -F 'codec_name' | sed 's/^.*=//'`; output should be checked in case it returns multiple lines (more than one audio stream) but should be able to handle cases where the audio isn't stream 0.

Comment: @Haravikk Great, I thought about sed but I'm not so good ad it.